# How to Change the z-index of Blogger Header

Tags: html, css, header, z-index, blogger

here's a link to my blog I've just started on Blogger: [My Blog](http://will-whitehead.blogspot.co.uk/)

My problem is that when I use the 'add background image' feature, the header containing the lettering 'Will Whitehead - Advertising Student' is also covered by the image, when I want it to stay white. I'm guessing that if I bring the header to the very front using z-index, it won't be covered by the image.

The thing is, I don't know the ID of the header. I looked at the header using the 'inspect element' feature on chrome and it's referred to as 'div.header-bar'.

Could someone please tell what code I need to write to successfully change the z-index of my header?

I'd really appreciate any help on this one.

Thanks in advance,

Will W

Answer (score 0):

This should bring the header to the front:

```
div.header-bar{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Put that in the css file after any styles referring to `.header-bar`.

Comment: he might need to set a position too

Comment: Cheers for trying to help me but it's not working :( Perhaps I could test to see if I'm targetting the right ID by changing the background color of the header. I guess the following code should do that: div.header-bar { background-color:green; }

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure your `div.header-bar` has a position value or else z-index won't work.

```
div.header-bar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: might be smart to identify the source div in the css.

Comment: Cheers for trying to help me but it's not working :( Perhaps I could test to see if I'm targetting the right ID by changing the background color of the header. I guess the following code should do that:

Comment: div.header-bar { background-color:green; }

Comment: It seems like you [fixed it](http://will-whitehead.blogspot.co.uk/) with `#header { position: fixed; z-index: 1000; }` no ?!?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the CSS. Should work for your issue.

```
.header-bar { position: relative; z-index:9999; }
```

If not, it could be because the image is overlaying on top of the parent container of header-bar. In which case you would have to set this:

```
#header-container { position: relative; z-index:9999; }
```

Comment: Cheers for trying to help me but it's not working :( Perhaps I could test to see if I'm targetting the right ID by changing the background color of the header. I guess the following code should do that:

Comment: .header-bar { background-color:green; }

Comment: This is what I'm having trouble identifying :/

Comment: Where does the image get added ? If you click inspect element on the image that you add (that covers your name) what element is it?